# Cypress Test returning to LocalHost:3000 in middle of test

Tags: reactjs, localhost, cypress

I'm attempting to run some relatively simple Cypress tests in a React app.
When running the tests, sometimes they pass. Sometimes they fail.

The fail is a result of Cypress visiting the base URL in the middle of the test
[image]

I don't understand why Cypress is attempting to revisit the base URL in the middle of a test.

```html
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

context('Actions', () => {

    /* Using this function didn't change the result */
    // before(() => {
    //     cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
    // })

    it('Hides / Shows definition list', () => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
        cy.get('button[name="Editors"]').click();
        cy.get('button[name="Search Definition Editor"]').click();
        cy.get('i[id="hideList"]').click();
        cy.get('i[id="showList"]', {
            timeout: 1500
        }).click();
    })     
})
```

Again - this exact test will sometimes pass. In those cases it doesn't return to localhost:3000 in the middle of the test.

Comment: You're adding `cy.visit()` in the `before()` hook so you should remove it from the `it()` method. That should solve your issue, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the case. I have the lines of code in the before hook commented out - I've tested both ways (in the test, and in the before hook) and have had the exact same outcome.